# Как запустить n-задач

Tags: c#, android-asynctask, асинхронность

Запускаю 3 задачи, которые выполняют каждый свою роль. Я думал что добавив `async Run` программа будет ждать пока все задачи выполнятся, но ошибся. Цикл сразу переходит на строку `int x=2;` . Как дождаться выполнения задач?

```
public async Task Run()
   {
       Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                 // Задача 1
            }
       Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                 // Задача 2
            }
       Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                 // Задача 3 
            }
   }

 private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            await Run(); // он не ожидает завершения задача, а сразу переходит вниз
            int x = 2;

         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `await`.

```
await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
             // Задача 1
        });
```

и т. д.

Или если вы хотите запустить задачи параллельно, то так:

```
var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
             // Задача 1
        });
var t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
             // Задача 1
        });
var t3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
             // Задача 1
        });
await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3);
```

Comment: задачи делают пост-гет запросы, однако активных соединение 3==кол-во ядер. как увеличить число?

Comment: @Radzhab: Думаю, что равенство количеству ядер — совпадение. Попробуйте `Task.Run` вместо `Task.Factory.StartNew`, кстати.